# How to Deploy Record Triggered Flow with custom error message via package.xml?

Tags: visual-workflow

Currently I am trying to deploy via package a record triggered flow with a custom error message and I keep getting the following error:

Invalid element reference PontuaSemEspec not found for target

Anyone have an ideia how to correct this ?

Comment: are you using V59.0 for your deployment? and source and target orgs need to be v59. Note Winter 24 (V59) deploys this weekend

Comment: Yes, I think it's an sfdx error, because after a few attempts to install and uninstall different sf extensions in VsCode the "CustomError" tag appeared in the meta... But today I tried to retrieve another flow and the tag didn't appear

Comment: Did anyone of you were able to resolve this? @MatheusVilela

Comment: @Avesh I didn't find any solution, I recommend you try updating the Salesforce cli and installing other versions of the salesforce extensions in VsCode. This is how I managed to get the tag.

Comment: Okay we are using copado so I think we have to wait until Salesforce fix this

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this by ensuring my package.xml had version 59.0.

Make sure to **retrieve** from the source org with version 59 (specified in the package.xml) in order to get the custom error metadata in the flow.

It'll include the following custom error element in the flow.

```
<customErrors>
        <name>Custom Error</name>
        <label>Custom Error</label>
        <locationX>1018</locationX>
        <locationY>1187</locationY>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Loop_Through_Errors_for_Custom_Error</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <customErrorMessages>
            <errorMessage>An existing Contact has already enrolled using the same Mobile Number.</errorMessage>
            <isFieldError>false</isFieldError>
        </customErrorMessages>
</customErrors>
```

**Deploy** to the target org, with the same package.xml (with version 59.0) and you should no longer experience this error.

If you are retrieving with version 58.0 or below, it will not include the custom error in the metdata - and you'll get this error when deploying.

Comment: Just a quick addendum to the answer: If you are running a project without the package.xml, you might need to update/bump up the API version in a file in the project root directory : sfdx-project.json 

You should see the key "sourceApiVersion" in there, update it there instead 

"sourceApiVersion": "59.0"